# How to edit a form in wizard and save its state for wizard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am making a wizard in React js. I am already populating data in form using get api call. Now I want to edit the data in form, that retains it's state over the application flow.

Comment: First, share parts of your code for more detailed help, Second you can use react context.

Comment: <TextInput type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={e => this.updateChange(e.target.value)}/> I am getting value in this text input from api call. I am updating its value calling updateChange method. Now I want is.. Whatever new value I update, it should retain its value

Comment: If you want to fetch data from api into this input then change it, and the changed data should be available to your entire app, you can use context, Could you provide a codesandbox link, to help you?

Comment: https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/examples/wizard/ take this as an example and assume that, in the second form, I already have the data which I am getting from the api call. I want that data to be editable, and that editable state should retain its value through out the wizard

Comment: read my answer and take a look at my demo link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux-Form allow you to pass custom props into `Field` so you can use this as a way to pass retrived value from your api into rendered component.

**Base on your example link you can do this:**

Modify renderField to accept custom prop `value` (or any other name you want) and pass it into input value.

```
const renderField = ({
  input,
  label,
  type,
  value,
  meta: { touched, error }
}) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} value={input.value ? 
            input.value : value} />
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Define state variable and change handler:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

const handleChange = e => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };
```

The initial value of your field (in this example 'Email') can be retrived from api as follow:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    /* your api call to fetch data */
    fetch(....)
    .then(res => setEmail(res.data));
  }, []);
```

Then in your field set props and set onChange handler

```
 <Field
        name="email"
        type="email"
        component={renderField}
        label="Email"
        props={{ value: email }}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-form-wizard-example-7v3iy?file=/WizardFormSecondPage.js

Comment: With your example, again I am facing the same problem. When I am editing the email id, and going to the next page. What I have editted, is no longer retaining it's value

Comment: I've fixed it, just a simple mistake :), input value should be value={input.value ? input.value : value} sandbox code is updated.

Comment: I am new to react and redux,  can you plz look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61316985/connectiong-wizard-to-redux