# connectiong wizard to redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
      action.ts:
      export const fetchField = (dispatch) => {
          console.log("!!!")
          const Form = new Service();
          Form
            .getProduct()
            .then((spec: Spec) => {
              dispatch({
                type: ACTIONS.SPEC.SHOW,
                spec : specification,
              });
            })
            .catch((err) => {});
        };

    appReducer:
    export interface FormsState {
     products: Array<Specification>
    }
    let initialState: FormsState = {
    products: []
    };

    export let appReducer = (
      state: FormsState = initialState,
      action
    ) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case ACTIONS.SPEC.SHOW:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
              products: [...action.products],
            });

        default:
          return state;
      }
    };

App.tsx:

const mapStateToProps = (state: FormsState) => {
  return state;
};


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchField: () => fetchField(dispatch),
  };
}
interface Props{
  fetchField: Function;
  details: Array<Specification>
}

 componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchSwaggerField();
}
render(){
<TextInput
            invalidText="A valid value is required"
            labelText="API title"
            type = "text"
            value={this.props.fetchField.length}
            name="title"


      /> 
}
```

I am  trying to get the value in text input from the redux api call, and expecting the value of api call in text field. Once I will be getting its value. I want to edit it value, and save its new value so that whenever i come back to the form, the new value should be retained

Comment: Please provide an online demo, Just a base structure.

Comment: link of online demo is not available. but instead of using hooks, I am using redux. this is how my reducer looks like ` switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.SPEC.UPDATE:
      const sample = Object.assign({}, state, {Details: action.specification});
      return sample;
      case ACTIONS.SPEC.UPDATE_TITLE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { title: action.setTitle() });
    default:`. first case is working fine, but in the second case i want to update the value the title which I am getting through api call

Comment: In short, i want to update the data present in the form and want to retain its value through out the wizard using redux

Comment: I completely know what you want, but I need an example of what you tried. to fixe it, to see your code errors, to advise you, to give you a complete answer.

Comment: never mind, i was able to fix it anyhow. will update the solution

Comment: i am stuck now with different issue, i want multiple input fields to add in my wizard on click of add button and that value should get store in redux, so whenever i come back to that form, those extra fields should exist. I am providing the link. Please check if you can help me with it. https://codesandbox.io/s/0Qzz3843?file=/WizardFormFirstPage.js

Comment: Ok, i'm gonna check it.

Comment: @I've added my answer, take a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the answer for your new issue to add/delete fields**

You can use `FieldArray`. The FieldArray component is how you render an array of fields ([ref](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/fieldarray.md/))

A sample code with add/delete:

```
// renderSubFields.js
const renderSubFields = (member, index, fields) => (
  <li key={index}>
    <button
      type="button"
      title="Remove Member"
      onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
    />
    <h4>Member #{index + 1}</h4>
    <Field
      name={`${member}.firstName`}
      type="text"
      component={renderField}
      label="First Name"
    />
    <Field
      name={`${member}.lastName`}
      type="text"
      component={renderField}
      label="Last Name"
    />
  </li>
);

const renderMembers = ({ fields }) => (
  <ul>
    <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>
      Add Member
    </button>
    {fields.map(renderSubFields)}
  </ul>
);
```

Then in your wizard page

```
<FieldArray name="members" component={renderMembers} />
```

Here is a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-form-wizard-example-m26bk?file=/WizardFormFirstPage.js:586-641

Comment: Thanks for your help but is it possible to do it through redux using action, reducer ?

Comment: redux-form handle everything. Why you need this functionality?? explain more please :)

Comment: Because that is the requirement assigned to me. Can you list me the advantages of using the redux form over the action and reducer?

Comment: Because actually redux-form do this for you (connect your React form components to your Redux store) Here is a good explanation https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/gettingstarted.md/. If you want to use redux-form so use built-in functionalities and apply customizations.